# How can i get the icons for redis and memcache just like Font awesome

Tags: font-awesome

I just want to use the **redis** and **memcache** icons in my web app. However, i try to search for brand icons about font awesome and finally find nothing about both except that about like **linux** and **Linkedin**.

How can i generate both two icons?

Answer (score 0):

Redis icon is available in this suite: http://fizzed.com/oss/font-mfizz